# Can I change web.config settings separately for different routes in ASP.NET MVC3?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis

I have an ASP.NET MVC3 application where routing is configured in such way that all requests to `/UsersRequests` are served by one controller and all requests to `/ServiceRequests` are served by another controller ad are treated slightly different.

Now I need to change `<system.webServer><security><access sslFlags>` property that is configured in web.config. If I do it at root level it has some undesired effects and so I'd like to have it changed for `/ServiceRequests` path only.

Is such change for one route only possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using `<location>` elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <!-- other sections here -->
  <location path="ServiceRequests">
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <!-- here goes the value that is changed for
             this location only
        -->
        <access sslFlags="SslNegotiateCert"/>
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- all the usual stuff goes here and only the stuff
         mentioned under "location" above will be overriden
         by values specified in there
     -->
  </system.WebServer>
</configuration>
```